# Can I create administrator user for ceph?

Tags: ceph

I can create basic user and it's subusers. Is it possible to create administrator user in ceph who can access all objects and buckets from all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **Yes**

And I know it's a tricky question. Because creating admin user is still not very straightforward.

The Ceph Storage Cluster provides an administrative API that enables users to execute administrative functions via the REST API. By default, users do **NOT** have access to this API. To enable a user to exercise administrative functionality, provide the user with administrative capabilities.

- To add administrative capabilities to a user, execute the following:

`radosgw-admin caps add --uid={uid} --caps={caps}`

- You can add read, write or all capabilities to users, buckets, metadata and usage (utilization). For example:

`--caps="[users|buckets|metadata|usage|zone|amz-cache|info|bilog|mdlog|datalog|user-policy|oidc-provider|roles|ratelimit]=[*|read|write|read, write]"`

For example:

`radosgw-admin caps add --uid=johndoe --caps="users=*;buckets=*"`

- To remove administrative capabilities from a user, execute the following:

`radosgw-admin caps rm --uid=johndoe --caps={caps}`